# CSS/HTML problem on Joomla config page (3.6.1 and 3.6.5)

Tags: css, joomla-3.6, administration, bugs

I have a rendering problem with my config page, which is loaded with

> /index.php?option=com_config

It shows up without any Styling - and without any embedded JavaScripts. When I look into the HTML code in the browser, I see that there is not html header/footer area. The first line of the page output is:

```
<form action="/administrator/index.php?option=com_config" id="application-form" method="post" name="adminForm" class="form-validate">
```

Other pages, such as /index.php?option=com_checkin show up perfectly.

I have compared my Joomla installation with the Joomla repository - there are no differences (just files added from my installations). So the installation seems to be ok.

I have this problem in version 3.6.1 and, after updating, also in version 3.6.5.

Comment: Try clearing the Joomla cache and also your browser cache if you haven't already.

Comment: I have cleared the cache multiple times. :-(

Comment: You could check your .htaccess file rules, if using, of course.
Just to check, you could also try a fresh installation under a subdomain in the same hosting environment.

Comment: Thanks. The .htaccess is standard from the installation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to use Admin Tools or RSFirewall to do a malware scan.  There are known cases where certain malware can cause this problem: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=902880

Comment: Your link helped me - I found this file: libraries/joomla/database/driver/bclass.php - this seems to be malware. When I delete this file my backend works again.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad you are back up and running :) Here is a good checklist for dealing with the security breach.   Since you have been hacked, there is probably other malware around.   https://docs.joomla.org/Security_Checklist/You_have_been_hacked_or_defaced

Answer (score 3):

I bet there is a fatal error somewhere, which prevents the complete execution and results to see an incomplete rendered page and the essential css/js files missing.

Enable error reporting and likely you will see what's wrong at the bottom of the page, where the rendering stops. Report back any of your findings.

It could also help if you would do a clean restoration of the joomla core, as usually such errors are the results of corrupted or missing core code files.

In some other cases this can be caused by 3rd party extensions - usually plugins - so as another step try disabling plugins and keep testing the page to see if there is any change.

Comment: Thank you, I checked the error logs and I enabled error reporting. No errors. I will test your suggestion with the extension.

Comment: @Gerfried in any case make sure error reporting is enabled for the page where you are checking - as it's very likely even if there are errors, something might stopping them from appearing/being reported.

Answer (score 2):

Got the same error in Joomla!

System top bar disappeared while in Admin->Global Configuration (com_config).

PHP error can only be seen in title (quite useless): "**Error: 0 Function name must be a string**".

Digging for several hours led me to **/libraries/joomla/database/driver/bclass.php**, removing this file fixes the error.

Hope this will save some hours for someone else..

[image: joomla without title bar]

Comment: See my comment on the accepted answer :-)

Comment: you're right, but I was not able to Google your solution until I found it myself ... I even was about to start a new issue in Joomla tracker:) so I added some keywords to my reply for any poor fellows that would fall in the same pit ))

Comment: While this insight was mentioned in a comment under the accepted answer, it is good/appropriate to post this resolving advice as a distinct answer.  This is the only answer that actually provides direct, legitimate resolving advice rather than assistance with diagnosing the source of the problem.  I don't mean to sound ungrateful regarding the other answers, but strictly speaking -- advice on how to isolate an issue or how to investigate are better as comments.  Answers are to be posted when the question is clear enough to accurately/confidently resolve.  Good answer, Mike.

Comment: To be clear, I am not requesting that the other answers be converted to comments under the question.  Oh, and Mike, please take our [tour].